# Calling $.ajax within javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

**This question is solved, even though the answer is irrelevant to the title. This was a badly structured question and to my disappointment I can't delete it as it is. Thanks for the help and looking at the code.**

I have 2 normal javascripts function and one jquery function for my application using google maps. In brief, it looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    initialize();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var markerE;
var theLocation;
var myLatlng;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markersArray = [];
var eventMarkerArr = [];
var retrievedLatLng;
var retrievedLatLngArr = [];

var map;
$(document).ready(function(){    
 $('#tabs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    if($(this).attr("href").substring(1)=='event')
    {   
        show('event');
        hide('location');
    }
    else if($(this).attr("href").substring(1)=='location')
    {
        show('location');
        hide('event');
    }
    });
   });


    function initialize() {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.7500);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     styles:[{
         featureType: "poi.attraction",
            stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
                ]},{
                featureType: "poi.business",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.government",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.medical",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.park",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.place_of_worship",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.school",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "poi.sports_complex",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
              },{
              }
            ]
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
      myOptions);

  if (postalArr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < postalArr.length; i++ ) {
            codeAddress(postalArr[i]);
        }
  }
  else
  {
      document.getElementById("event_list").value = "There are no events!";
  }

  var locationPin = 'images/green-pin.png'; 


}     

var address;
var eventPin = "images/blue-pin.png";
function codeAddress(postal) {      
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': postal + ", Singapore"}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        retrievedLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
        var eventwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var markerE = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            icon: eventPin,
        });
        markerE.mycategory = "event";
        markerE.setVisible(false);
        google.maps.event.addListener(markerE, 'click', function(){
            eventwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "hello",
            });
            eventwindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+retrievedLatLng+"&sensor=false",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(json){
          if(json.status == 'OK')
            {
            alert("success");
            }
    }
});
        eventMarkerArr.push(markerE);
        retrievedLatLngArr.push("codeAddress:"+retrievedLatLng);
        alert(retrievedLatLngArr[0]);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

The reason why I'm doing this is because I can't seem to get `latlng`. What i did at first was to initialize the maps with `window.onload = function(){ initialize() }` and call the .ajax function in a `$(window).load(function(){...});` I can't get it right either ways.

Sorry if this sounds confusing. I'll add in more details if this isn't enough.

**Edit:**

`results[0].geometry.location` is the latitude longtitude that is produced from reverse geocoding a 6 digit postal code. I want the full address, but only have the 6 digit postal code. The latitude and longtitude is used to also place a marker on the google map. So to get the full address I'm trying to get a json result using the url provided by google.

**More Edit:**
Added full length of code

Comment: What is `results`? Does your `$.ajax()` call not have a success callback? It's good to remove unnecessary details when posting code, but in this case you've removed way too much. (And note that a "jQuery function" _is_ a normal function.)

Comment: You'd need to split the latlng to lat+"," + lng

Comment: Your example is quite incomplete. What is `someAddress`? What is `results`? What is your actual problem?

Comment: You can't return the result in codeAddress as your ajax function is asynchronous.

Comment: i am confused can you tell me are you geocoding address? and if yes then codeaddress have already latlng how come ?

Comment: $(window).load(function(){...}) executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images . just to add information

Comment: @FelixKling My actual problem is that latlng is undefined no matter where I call it other than within codeAddress. I was thinking whether calling from different locations and functions would change but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: @nnnnnn results[0].geometry.location is the latitude longtitude that is produced from reverse geocoding a 6 digit postal code. Please see the edit for more details. I had read somewhere that jquery functions should not be called from pure js functions, thus the title

Comment: Just on the "pure js" versus jQuery issue: there's no problem at all calling jQuery functions including `$.ajax()` from non-jQuery code. jQuery is all JS too, and the browser doesn't know or care which bit is "jQuery". What you can't do, with or without jQuery, is manipulate DOM elements that haven't been parsed yet - that's why code that touches the DOM should go in a document ready or load handler, or in a script block at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSUMING that results[0].geometry.location is ALREADY a valid location. I do not see this to be a fact, but you might have that already

```
  url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+results[0].geometry.location.lat() +","+results[0].geometry.location.leg()+"&sensor=false";
```

You might want to check if the seperation with comma is correct

Comment: results[0].geometry.location is a valid location within codeAddress but not anywhere else.

Comment: I just tried the above out, and its giving me _Object( 1.302939,103.82309600000008) has no method 'len'_